# Lazy loading does not load ICollection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem loading an `ICollection` object via lazy Loading.

```
public class Product
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string OrderNum { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfPurchased { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<OrderedItem> OrderedItems { get; set; }

   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
 }

 public class OrderedItem
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Profit { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
  }
```

Whenever I load data to `Product`, all the properties can be loaded except the `ICollection` property. Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: Are the foreign keys defined in migration files ?

Comment: @Béranger Yes. There's a foreign key defined when creating the OrderedItem

Comment: @hafizabdullah Did you disposed your context before trying to access your ICollection object ?

Comment: Rules for lazy loading: 1 context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
2 : context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
3 :  Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual.

Comment: @hafizabdullah please check all 3 mentioned in my comments

Comment: @Béranger Yup. If you look at the Product class, there's also a Customer property and it loads just fine.

Comment: @YashveerSingh Yes I have checked all of them. If not, the Customer property also would not be loaded. In this case, the ICollection is the one that did not load. The Customer property have no problem

Comment: @hafizabdullah you can try to explicitly define the relationship with fluent api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: what is the error you get after trying to access to ICollection<OrderedItem> OrderedItems

Comment: it will be easier if you paste you DBContext file

Comment: @hafizabdullah : I tried with you model classes a sample application for me It worked Please check my answer below . I just removed customer and Item class just for simplicity . I pasted the  output and database tables as well let me know if this helps :)

Comment: @Béranger Thanks. I don't know why but using Fluent API got it working

Comment: So you can use fluent API or data annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi I tried this on my local pc and it worked . Below are the Model classes and dbContext class . I removed some Properties to make it simple . Just on model creating I added one line .

EF Classes

```
        public class Product
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string OrderNum { get; set; }
                public DateTime DateOfPurchased { get; set; }
                public int CustomerId { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<OrderedItem> OrderedItems { get; set; }


            }

            public class OrderedItem
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public int ProductId { get; set; }
                public int? Quantity { get; set; }
                public int? ItemId { get; set; }
                public decimal? TotalPrice { get; set; }
                public decimal? Profit { get; set; }

                public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
            }
```

MY DBCOntext Class :

```
     public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SampleDbContext()
            : base("name=SampleDBConnection")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        }



        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<OrderedItem> OrderedItems { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(c => c.OrderedItems);



        }
    }
```

Output  :[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solved it by using the Fluent API

Comment: @hafizabdullah glad I hope you like my answer and explanation.